# IntelliJ Tomcat not opening html or jsp file brings up error 404

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

Tomcat is not opening the jsp or html files, Tomcat seems to run but brings error 404 everytime I try to call Home.html or Home.jsp the page using the url.

Here is the directory where home is located, it is inside the webapp folder:
[image: Directory]

Here is the Tomcat deployment configuration:
[image]

Here is my **web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>com.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>First Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.common.Application</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>First Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here is **pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebJava</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebJava</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.58</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can someone explain it step by step because there is no general tutorial on the internet how to deal with this basic problem that I struggled to solve, am I missing a dependency or  something in the web.xml file?
Here is how the error looks:

[image]

Comment: Isn't your web.xml, with a dangling /* ?

Comment: Inside my file it looks ok, don't know why it looks here like that.

Comment: Can you provide a project?

Comment: Setup the Tomcat manager app, see https://www.oxxus.net/tutorials/tomcat/tomcat-manager and after deployment check what context the deployed application has. This will also allow you to use the Tomcat Manager App for deployment, so you can compare it with IDE's one.

Answer (score 0):

Did this happen after adding the gson dependency because everything stopped working for me when i added it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).